# Amazon $s3->create_object() returns 200 but object isn't created

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to S3 using PHP, and it seems like it should be working but the image doesn't appear.  The code to upload is this:

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3(array("key"=><mykey>,"secret"=><mysecret>));
$s3->ssl_verification = false;
if ($s3->if_bucket_exists($i_sBucket)) {
    $obj = $s3->create_object($i_sBucket,$i_sFileName,array('body'=>$i_sData));
    if ($obj->isOK()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        //log error
    }
} else {
    // log error
}
```

When I run this, I get these important values:

```
$obj->isOK() = true
$obj["status"] = 200
$obj["body"] = false
$obj["_info"]["url"] = the appropriate destination URL
$obj["_info"]["http_code"] = 200
```

But if I check the bucket through the web interface, or try to access the file, it's not there.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

What values do you have for $i_sBucket and $i_sFileName?
My guess is that those variables don't match any existing folder.